# Problem with manually inserting references in Latex

Tags: biblatex, citing

I am using the following simple code

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}

Life is very beautiful as confirmed in \cite{A2010}.

\begin{thebibliography}{xx}

\bibitem{A2010} J.~A, ``How beautiful is life,'' in {\em Proc. IEEE}, Denver, CO, Sept. 2010, pp.~xxx-xx.

\end{thebibliography} 
    
\end{document}
```

and I get as output the following pdf:

[image]

However, I would like the reference to appear as `[1]`. I have tried to remove `\usepackage{biblatex}` since I have read that this creates conflict with thebibliography, but then the code does not compile and I get the following error:

```
Undefined control sequence. \abx@aux@refcontext
```

Any idea on what might do the trick?

Comment: remove biblatex, delete the aux-file and try again (compile at least twice).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`biblatex` is not compatible with a manually generated `thebibliography` environment. If you want to use a manual `thebibliography`, you cannot load `biblatex`.

Remove the line `\usepackage{biblatex}` from your document, delete the `.aux`, `.bcf` (and if present also the `.bbl`) files. Then recompile (at least twice) with LaTeX (where "LaTeX" is your favourite flavour of LaTeX: pdfLaTeX, LuaLaTeX, XeLaTeX, ...). If you are using Overleaf delete the cache (https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Clearing_the_cache) or recompile from scratch.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}


\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}

Life is very beautiful as confirmed in \cite{A2010}.

\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem{A2010} J.~A, ``How beautiful is life,'' in {\em Proc. IEEE}, Denver, CO, Sept. 2010, pp.~xxx-xx.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

then gives

[image: Life is very beautiful as confirmed in [1].]

Comment: Thank you so much, this made the trick! Indeed the problem was the presence of previously compiled ancillary files (.aux, .bbl)...